# click event - how to make click event revert back to original gradually

Tags: javascript, three.js, click, mouseclick-event

So I have worked hard to get this code correct thus far. Basically my click event makes my shapes DECAY gradually start being affected. It works perfectly as I wanted. But my question is when I let go of holding down my mouse or finger it automatically jumps back to the original frame. Can I please get some help on how to make it gradually go back (or gradually end) like how it starts? that way its a fluid animation from start to finish.

Here's my Click event code

```js
    decaybackup = config.shader.decay;
    world.resize()
});
let interval='';
let myshape = document.getElementById('shapeId');

myshape.addEventListener('pointerdown', function(event) { 
    interval = setInterval(()=>{        
        config.shader.decay += .001;
    },1)
});
myshape.addEventListener('pointerup', function(event) {
    config.shader.decay = decaybackup;
    clearInterval(interval)
  interval = '';
});
```

also here is a read only link to my site if you need a visual of what im talking about and can also see any code I have added...

[enter link description here](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/voxstudios?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=voxstudios&preview=23bc1f318ca3d4f5dfec2eb72948e82f&workflow=preview)

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You need to use `setInterval()` in the pointerup listener, similar to what you do in pointerdown.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! where would I use the other setInterval()?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` to decrement `decay` back to `decaybackup` similar to the way you increment it during pointerdown.

```js
let undecayInterval;

myshape.addEventListener('pointerup', function(event) {
  config.shader.decay = decaybackup;
  clearInterval(interval);
  clearInterval(undecayInterval);
  undecayInterval = setInterval(() => {
      config.shader.decay -= 0.001;
      if (config.share.decay <= decaybackup) {
        clearInterval(undecayInterval);
      }, 1);
  }
});
```